# Matlab out of memory error while solving ODE

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory, ode

I have to integrate an ODE of 8 variable in matlab. My simulation time is 5e9 with a time step of 0.1. But it shows memory error. I am working with i7 core ,2.6Ghz CPU with 8GB RAM. How can I simulate ODEs for a large time samples?

Comment: I know that it's not the most accurate way, but what about restarting the simulation after some time?

Comment: Does it serve a specific good purpose to generate and store 5e10 state vectors requiring 8·8·5e10 byte = 3.2e12 byte = 3.2 Terabyte? Did you provision to write this to disk as it seems unlikely that you can hold this in memory?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working on 64 Bit version of MATLAB you might want to let MATLAB squeeze the memory to the edge using the `Preferences -> MATLAB -> Workspace -> MATLAB Array Size Limit`.

If you are getting this erro because you really mximized the memory in the system do the following:

1. Make sure you're using 64 Bit OS and 64 Bit version of MATLAB.
2. Before you call the ODE function, clear manually (using the [`clear()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html) function) variables you don't need any more (Or can recreate once the function finishes).
3. Increase the swap file of your system. It will help with larger memory consumption but might make things much slower.

You can find more tips and tricks in [Resolve "Out of Memory" Errors](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html) and [`memory()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memory.html).